# How to display string that contains HTML in twig template?

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

How can I display a string that contains HTML tags in a twig template?

My PHP variable contains this HTML and text:

```
$word = '<b> a word </b>';
```

When I do this in my twig template:

```
{{ word }}
```

I get this:

```
&lt;b&gt; a word &lt;b&gt;
```

I want this instead:

```
<b> a word </b>
```

Is it possible to get this easily?

Comment: I won't add this as an answer, but an alternative approach for people reaching this question is to store values in [Markdown](https://packagist.org/packages/michelf/php-markdown), like [StackOverflow does](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Then you could create a Twig filter with [automatic escaping](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#automatic-escaping), since you can trust the HTML to be safe. No `raw` needed, and your stored values are human readable!

Answer (score 456, accepted):

Use raw keyword, https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/api.html#escaper-extension

```
{{ word | raw }}
```

Comment: When doing a replace it is not working for me. {{ word | replace( {(word_to_replace) : '<b>' ~ (word_to_replace) ~ '</b>' }) | raw }}
Any idea?

Comment: UPDATE: I solved it by adding it to another variable using 'set', then {{ word | raw }} works fine.

Answer (score 88):

You can also use:

```
{{ word|striptags('<b>')|raw }}
```

so that only `<b>` tag will be allowed.

Comment: I'd say this version is preferable if you want to allow only a few tags.

Comment: How do you allow multiple tags?

Answer (score 40):

```
{{ word|striptags('<b>,<a>,<pre>')|raw }}
```

if you want to allow multiple tags

Answer (score 1):

if you don't need variable, you can define text in
*translations/messages.en.yaml* :
    `CiteExampleHtmlCode: "<b> my static text </b>"`

then use it with twig:
*templates/about/index.html.twig*
`… {{ 'CiteExampleHtmlCode' }}`
or if you need multilangages like me:
`… {{ 'CiteExampleHtmlCode' | trans }}`

Let's have a look of https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html for more information about translations use.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me only with "**render**" before striptags:

node--mycontenttype.html.twig:

```
{{ content.field_my_field|render|striptags }}
```