# Using escape and raw in twig?

Tags: symfony, escaping, twig

I have an article that has smart quotes in it, so I need to escape the article content.  However, if I use

```
      article.body| e
```

to escape the article, the html does not show up as formatted.  And if I use

```
      article.body| raw
```

the article is displayed correctly as html but the smart quotes are not escaped in the content.

Does anyone know how to escape content while correctly displaying the html?

Comment: Check this solution as creating twig filter http://stackoverflow.com/a/8355239/6056191

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a strategy for the [escape filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/escape.html).

`'html'` won't work for you here because it internally uses PHP's [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

`'html'` is the default strategy when using `{{ var|e }}`

You will need to create a custom escaping strategy for your use case.

... but if it's only the quotes which need to be replaced you could do a simple `preg_replace` on `PrePersist` and `PreUpdate` using Doctrine's [Lifecyle Events](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html).

Comment: It still only shows up as unformatted html with all the tags and such as output :/

Comment: oh sorry guess i misread the question. you need to create a custom escaping strategy for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

to show the special characters we can use like this {{ '<'|e }} it will print only angle angle bracket '<'