# PHP put html inside a twig variable?

Tags: javascript, php, html, symfony, twig

Hello I am trying to try something that is expieremental and not really sure if it's possible. I have a twig template with some html that is duplicated on the page and I am wondering if it's possible to create a variable in twig that holds a snippet of html (must include html markup) that i can then call throughout the page instead of repeating myself.... thanks in advance

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>
       <title>My Webpage</title>
     </head>
     <body>

     {% set greet = "<strong>hello</strong>" %}

     <div id="1"> {{ greet }} Jeremy</div>
     <div id="1"> {{ greet }} Davis</div>

   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: `{{ greet|raw }}`?

Comment: @Jon wow simple as that! Thanks man!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display a string that contains HTML in twig template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355123/display-a-string-that-contains-html-in-twig-template)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 {% set greet = "<strong>hello</strong>" %}

 <div id="1"> {{ greet|raw }} Jeremy</div>
 <div id="1"> {{ greet|raw }} Davis</div>
```

Comment: if hello is in a variable then how it possible?

Comment: Late to the party, but like so: `{% set var_hello = "hello" %} {% set greet = "<strong>" ~ var_hello ~ "</strong>" %}`