# Output from field of type HTML prints tags verbatim (BOLT-CMS / Twig)

Tags: twig, bolt-cms, twig-filter

In Bolt CMS, I have a field defined like so:

*contenttypes.yaml*

```
details:    # thats my new content type
  name: (...)
  (...)
  fields:
    (...)
    contentblocks:
      type: block
      label: Content
      fields:
        freetext:
          label: Formatted Text
          fields:
            content:
              type: html
  (...)
```

However, now when i display this in my template with ...

```
{% setcontent nameAddr = 'data/name-addr' %}
{% for group in nameAddr.contentblocks %}
  {% if group.block == 'freetext' %}
    {{group.content}}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

... I get output like this in the page (via view-source):

```
&lt;p&gt;a&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;
b&lt;/p&gt;
```

So the tags are somehow printed verbatim.

(I am not entering the tags in WYSIWYG mode.)

Im a bit confused since everything seems identical to the documentation [(1)](https://docs.bolt.cm/3.4/fields/block) [(2)](https://docs.bolt.cm/howto/resource-contenttype).

Would be great if someone could help me out. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{group.content | raw}}
```

See https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html

> Bolt uses the Twig template engine. As such, all default twig {{
>   |filters }} also work in Bolt. Most of these have a similar meaning in
>   plain PHP or Javascript. The available filters are: abs, batch,
>   capitalize, convert_encoding, date, date_modify, default, escape,
>   first, format, join, json_encode, keys, last, length, lower, merge,
>   nl2br, number_format, raw, replace, reverse, round, slice, sort,
>   split, striptags, title, trim, upper, url_encode.

Comment: Does not have any effect, unfortunately.

Comment: `autoescape` did not have any effect so I think the answer should not read "try `autoescape` or something else".

Comment: Updated, originally I kept autoescape as it could solve similar issues, but you are right.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `raw` filter, as in:

```
{{group.content | raw}}
```

cf [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355123/display-a-string-that-contains-html-in-twig-template#8355239) and documentation of [`raw`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html).