# Rendering HTML with Vue combined inside a Vue component

Tags: vue.js, twig, vuejs3

Im trying to upgrade a project from Vue 2 to Vue 3 and there is a component in there with collections of different Vue components.

The way it worked in Vue 2 is by calling a Twig template (for example: field.twig) in Twig and sending that to Vue to compile using the :is attribute and Vue.compile method (`<div :is"compile(element.content) ..."`).

This is what the Twig templates sends to Vue:

[image: Screenshot of Twig template]

However in Vue 3 this doesnt seem to work anymore. There is nothing getting rendered and if I just use `{{ element.content }}` in the template it returns the raw code.

I have tried multiple things to get the html mixed with Vue to render (v-html, v-runtime-template) but none of these seemed to fix the issue.

Vue Component: [Collections Component](https://github.com/bolt/core/blob/vue-upgrade/assets/js/app/editor/Components/Collection.vue)

Twig Template: [Collections Template](https://github.com/bolt/core/blob/vue-upgrade/templates/_partials/fields/collection.html.twig)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display string that contains HTML in twig template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355123/how-to-display-string-that-contains-html-in-twig-template)

Comment: No unfortunately not @DarkBee There is a Vue Component (Collections.vue) and this recieves HTML code (with a Vue Component embedded) from Twig. And that needs to be rendered inside Collections.vue.

Comment: The twig template is rendered (serverside), before sending it off to Vue though?

Comment: Yes. But I dont need to display the string in Twig it needs to be displayed via Vue. The string only gets build in twig via a macro but it needs to be compiled in Vue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/distributed-vue-applications-loading-components-via-http/ or https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-runtime-template-compiler but I am not sure if these work in Vue 3 ...

Comment: Hi! I've already tried the Vue3 equivalent of the runtime template compiler and this didn't work because I cant store the string inside the data() method. The string is a object inside a for loop.

Comment: Then you might need to compile the Twig templates to render functions or Web Components on the server and send these to your app.

Comment: This could solve it but how will I implement this when the string gets build via a Twig Macro.

Comment: I am confused - you said that `the string is a object [inside a for loop]`. Perhaps you can convert those Vue components that are used by the Twig macro into Web Components - and then simply use `v-html` to render them ?

Comment: I already tried using the `v-html` for the string but the field component inside of that string is `<editor-textarea>...</editor-textarea>`. And `v-html` doesn't render components because it only renders html. It doesn't compile the Vue component.

Comment: Perhaps you misread what I wrote - I suggested converting these Vue components that are used by Twig to WebComponents which will be registered by the root Vue instance of your app. Then you can render them in `v-html` and the browser will pickup the corresponding Web Component(s).

Comment: https://cwco.io/documentation