# How to apply Twig filter replace() to rendered result which is not a string?

Tags: twig, twig-filter

There is a variable preparing in PHP for rendering in a Twig template like

`{{ product.variations.0.add_to_cart_form }}`

And I need to change the final rendered result by adding my additional string to it.

The problem is, the value of the key `add_to_cart_form` is not a string. It's maybe a result of executing some PHP function or is an element of an array. I don't understand how exactly it's prepared in PHP, but I need to change the final result simply by applying the filter `|replace({'some_string':'some_string and_more'})`. If it's possible.

If I put the line `{{ product.variations.0.add_to_cart_form }}` to a new template, include it in the parent template and add to a new variable like

```
{% set test %}
    {% include directory ~ '/templates/addtocartform.html.twig' %}
{% endset %}
{% set test = test.replace({'some_string':'some_string and_more'}) %}
{{ test }}
```

I get nothing on the page. Again, as I understand because the variable is not a string.

Is there a way to "convert" it to a string and then apply the filter `|replace()` regardless of the type of the variable ?

Something like `template_to_string` (do not be confused with `template_from_string`)

Comment: `test.replace` is not a valid syntax this would `test` to be an object or an array. Did you actually try to do [`{{ test|replace(...) }}`](https://twigfiddle.com/d0dmdy)?

Comment: @DarkBee Sorry, it was a typo. Now if I try `|replace()` I get `<drupal-render-placeholder callback="commerce_product.lazy_builders:addToCartForm" arguments="0=2&amp;1=full&amp;2=1&amp;3=en" token="qUuriDxuihYvLHsqv1s2lk_NCCHo2YOAAcNz"></drupal-render-placeholder>`. I see it's Drupal-specific issue

Comment: The filter replace doesn't mark a string as safe. If you want output "real" HTML you would need to apply the filter `raw` as well. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355123/how-to-display-string-that-contains-html-in-twig-template)

Comment: @DarkBee Yes, the `{{ test|raw }}` renders the real HTML instead of `<drupal-render-placeholder...`, but still without the result of applying the `|replace()` filter. Even if I duplicate the `|raw` also before the `replace()` i.e. `{% set test = test|raw %}{% set test = test|replace(...) %}`

Comment: No, you'd apply the filter raw *after* you've used the filter `replace`, e.g. `{{ var|replace({'x':'y';})|raw }}`